How to install curl on a linux container being built by windows server
I currently have a windows build server. Unfortunately I can't change that to be linux. I require my container to have the curl command but I am unsure how to install curl while in a Windows Server.
Through a linux build server I can use this command in my Dockerfile RUN apt-get -y update; apt-get -y install curl and this works But this command does not work through windows server
May I ask how do I install curl onto my container when building through Windows Server.

In Powershell there is a curl command which should already be in the image. It's an alias of Invoke-Webrequest IIRC and some of the options are a bit different and it's not as capable as the real curl. Maybe you can use that.

I specifically need curl unfortunately as the image gets deployed to a linux machine. @HansKilian

Ah, OK. I misunderstood. Unfortunately, I don't think it's possible to build Linux images on Windows. You can with WSL2, but that runs a Linux VM under the covers and if I understand you correctly, that's not an option?

Have you put Docker in Linux Containers mode? Assuming WSL2/Hyper-V etc is installed you should be able to build and push linux containers on your Windows host (think of it like when docker is in linux mode the cli is talking to a linux vm running on windows- so it is a linux container). Potential issue here is you cant have both windows & linux container support running at the same time (but you can toggle the mode easily enough). You might get better answers over on superuser.com as this is off topic for S/O. Voting to close

It largely depends upon the container type you're using.
If it is Debian based only then it'll follow the apt install commands.
For RHEL system (Fedora/Opensuse,etc) you'll need dnf and such
